# Avoid Killing of Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want create an **Activity** in **Android** which never kill (on long press of **Back Button**)  until specific condition fulfill.

How I can achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the back button and only let the activity finish if the 'conditions have been met'.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(conditionIsMet) {
         //The condition was met, close the activity
         finish;
    } else  { 
         //Cancel the button press
         return;
    }
}
```

I hope this is the answer you were looking for, but your question wasn't too clear.